# How to create desktop shortcut for IE including user name and password?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

I want to create a shortcut for a link which should be open in IE (not in firefox) and that page has 2 input box 1.  for username  2. for password.

I want to create shortcut for IE including username and password.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only tell IE to remember the password to this site. Then, when you use the shortcut, or just go to the site, IE will fill in the boxes for you.